# Why do I always get an HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error when debugging a web app under IIS 7.5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to get Orchard CMS running under IIS, but I keep getting an HTTP 500 response. I have built and run the source code from within VS2012, but even with exceptions set to break when thrown, VS doesn't break, and I still get a very unhelpful and opaque HTTP 500 response.

I created a new web site called Orchard, pointing to the source folder of the web app, i.e. *C:\Development\Orchard.Source.1.6\src\Orchard.Web*, and bound it to host name *orchard.local*, which I added to my hosts file under 127.0.0.1. I have read that I need to set file system permissions for IIS_IUSRS when running the web site under IIS; I don't know if I still do for debugging under VS. I would have though VS would take care of that. Then, for some reason I don't have that group, I only have an IIS_WPG group, which is supposed to be for IIS6.

How can I diagnose what is causing this Internal Server Error if I can't even get VS to break on the exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was happening because I installed IIS after Visual Studio, so ASP.NET 4 wasn't registered. I solved it by running

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i
```

Comment: This is obsolete in w10. You need to go to "Turn windows features on or off" and enable this on the IIS. Still marked as useful because is the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the orchard logs? You'll find them in the App_Data folder. 500 errors should be logged in there

Comment: Nothing in the logs. Well, nothing gets added when I get a fresh 500 response.

Comment: Try running the application pool as network service instead of the IUSR account - could be permission related.

Comment: Which version of IIS are you running? Sorry - ignore that, just seen it in the title

Comment: Presumably the App Pool is running .Net 4 Integrated?

Comment: Yes, it is running v4 integrated.

Comment: Is there any info in the 500 error message? Is it a .Net YSOD or an IIS error message? Is the site running under Full Trust? If you use Chrome developer tools, Firebug or Fiddler, do you get any extra info about the error? (brain dump)

Comment: Nothing. Let's not continue in comments here, I will put this on a back-burner for now.

Answer (score -1):

I restarted my system and that seamed to work, then my friend had the same problem and he restarted visual studio and that seamed to work